# accessing struct members using pointer to pointer

Tags: c++, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list, function-definition

I have a program like below, when I try to access a struct member using pointer to pointer it says the expression must have a pointer to class type. Please tell me how can I access data element of the struct object using a pointer to pointer

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
struct Node{
    int data;
    Node* next;
};

void addnode(Node** node, int val)
{
    if (node == NULL){
        *node = new Node();
        *node->data = val;

    }
}



int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Node* node;
    addnode(&node, 10);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The compiler thinks you want `*(node->data)` due to operator precedence. Specify the order you want with `(*node)->data`.

Comment: Use  `(*node)->data = val;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `*node->data = val;` there are 3 operators involved.

- `operator*` to dereference
- `operator->` to access a member
- `operator=` to do the assignment

In which order will these happen? According to [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) which states:

| Precedence | Operator |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | `operator->` |
| 3 | `operator*` |
| 16 | `operator=` |

`node->data` will happen first and then the result will be dereferenced - so you have `*(node->data)` on the left hand side.

You need to dereference `node` first and can use `(`... `)` to override the precedence rules:

```cpp
(*node)->data = val;
```

Also note that your original `Node*` is uninitialized and reading it (like you do in `if(node == NULL)` ) will cause the program to have undefined behavior. Initialize it to `nullptr`:

```
Node* node = nullptr; // here
addnode(&node, 10);
```

Answer (score 2):

`*node->data = val;` is equivalent to `*(node->data) = val;`, but what you want is `(*node)->data = val;` (so you need to add the parens).

Answer (score 1):

It's an order of operations thing. It needs to be `(*node)->data = val`. Also note that the `if` statement is doing the opposite of what you want: `*node` to not be an error you need to test that `node` is *not* null not that it is null.

Answer (score 1):

For starters you need to initialize the pointer node in main

```
Node* node = nullptr;
```

Secondly this expression

```
*node->data = val;
```

is equivalent to

```
* ( node->data ) = val;
```

due to the precedence of operators  because postfix operators including the operator  `->` have a higher precedence than unary operators like the dereference operator `*`.

At least you need to write

```
( *node )->data = val;
```

But in any case the function does not make a sense.

If you need to add a new node to the beginning of the singly linked list then the function will look the following way

```
void addnode(Node** node, int val)
{
    *node = new Node { val, *node };
}
```

Or without using double pointers like

```
void addnode( Node* &node, int val)
{
    node = new Node { val, node };
}
```

In this case the function is called like

```
addnode(node, 10);
```

If you want to append a new node to the end of the singly-linked list then in this case the function can look like

```
void addnode(Node** node, int val)
{
    while ( *node ) node = &( *node )->next;
    *node = new Node { val, *node };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The **problem** is that due to **operator precedence** the statement `*node->data = val;` is equivalent to:

```
*(node->data) = val;
```

The above statement doesn't work because dereferencing `node` will give us `Node*` which does not have any member called `data` as it is a non-class type.
To **solve** this you need to override this behavior by adding parenthesis around `*node` as shown below:

```
(*node)->data = val;
```

Additionally, the variable `node` inside `main` is uninitialized. You should initialize it as shown below:

```
 Node* node = nullptr;
```